# How to display SWF files or macromedia contents of website inside android app

Tags: android, flash, android-webview, android-support-library, swfloader

I have an app that displays news of famous websites but i want to add some more news sites and e-paper of famous newspapers.But those E-paper uses adobe flash player or something others to load epapers.I want to load them in my android app.

As there is no support for flash in android now.Installing adobe flash apk is also nt a solution . I need your help.Plz help me out..

Comment: Or you could investigate what format this electronic paper is packaged as (is it PDF?). SWF is just a set of instructions so someone wrote code in their Flash app to display the text and pictures from whatever original file, check what other files the SWF code loads and one of them is the actual document, now write code to display that document (ie: load the same PDF that the SWF is loading)...

Comment: I have tried that but it didn't work..thank u for your answer..do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Do you have a link to one of these e-paper sites so I check what they're doing?

Comment: Have a look.. http://therisingnepal.org.np/epaper/view?paper=risingnepal

Comment: I used Chrome browser (and opened its Developer Tools). That shows me the SWF (app) just loads jpegs and displays them in a special effect (flip book). surely you can display jpeg in Android? The SWF loads some JSON file that has links to the jpegs (**[see it here](http://therisingnepal.org.np/epaper/getdata/risingnepal?time=28-06-2016)**. For each image just find the word "largest" and get the following http adress up to the ".jpg" part. Fix the final jpeg URL link (ie: remove any backslash and keep only the forward slashes so `http:/\/\www` becomes `http://www` etc)

Comment: thank you so much. That was all i needed